# how can I add more options in "Choose terminal" dropdown using OFBiz

Tags: ofbiz

I am new on OFBiz. Can anybody tell me how can I add more options in the "Choose terminal" dropdown? On Web POS login pop-up screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4DXS.png)

I have tried to find the answer in the documentation but there was no proper answer.